# cannot resolve FragmentTransaction.add() method . Why am I getting this error?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I have already looked at the other answers but none of them help me. 
I made sure to use `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` so that's not the problem.

**MainActivity.java**

```
     package com.example.nirvan.fragmentsexample2;


    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myFragment myfragment=new myFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer,myfragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
   }
```

**Error** :

```
Error:(20, 28) error: no suitable method found for add(int,myFragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; myFragment cannot be converted to Fragment)
```

Why am I getting this?

In **activity_main.xml** I have a `FrameLayout`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer">

</FrameLayout>
```

**myFragment.java**

```
package com.example.nirvan.fragmentsexample2;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;    
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
public class myFragment extends Fragment
{
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle 
 savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment,container,false);
}

public myFragment(){}
}
```

**fragment.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:paddingLeft="145dp"
    android:text="fragment One"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sloppy mistake . You should call **`v4.app.Fragment`** instead of  **`app.Fragment`** .

Open **myFragment.java**

**Don't**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

**Do**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Answer (score 4):

Change this

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

to

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

in `myFragment` class

Also i would suggest to have proper naming convention for your fragment.

No need for `android:orientation="vertical"` in relative layout.